# Regex File Naming Convention

Tags: regex

I'm looking for files that have the following convention:

> 123.987654321.FileName.pdf

1. The extension can be  (.pdf,.tif,.tiff)
2. The numbers can be letter or numbers and no specific

I have this so far:

```
\\d+.\\w.\\w.
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `.` in your pattern.

```
\d+\.\d+\.\w+\.\w+
```

https://regex101.com/r/EzeAir/1

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer.

```
\d+\.\d+\.\w+\.\w+
```

Comment: One doesn't *parrot* someone else's answer and claim it is the answer. Delete this and mark spencer.sm as the answer.